# Refreshing a page returns [object CSSStyleDeclaration]

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I edit a content and saved changes, it shows [object CSSStyleDeclaration] instead of my updated content when refreshing the page.

```js
function newElement() {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let inputvalue = document.querySelector("#myInput").value;
  let savedNote = document.createTextNode(inputvalue);
  li.appendChild(savedNote);
  if (inputvalue === '') {
    alert("Please write something")
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#myNotes").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.querySelector("#myInput").value = '';
}

function saveEdits() {
  let editElement = document.querySelector("#saved-notes");
  editElement = document.querySelector("#myNotes");
  let userVersion = editElement.innerHTML;
  userVersion = editElement.style;
  localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;
  document.querySelector("#update").innerHTML = "Edits saved. Refresh the page to see changed content";
}

function checkEdits() {
  if (localStorage.userEdits != null)
    document.querySelector("#saved-notes").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
  document.querySelector("#myNotes").style = localStorage.userEdits;
}
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body onload="checkEdits()">

  <div id="myDiv" class="new-note">
    <textarea id="myInput"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="newElement()" class="save-button">Create</button>
    <button onclick="saveEdits()" class="edit-button">Save Changes</button>
  </div>

  <div id="update"></div>
  <div id="saved-notes"></div>
  <ul id="myNotes">
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

It will work if I removed `userVersion = editElement.style;`, but there will no CSS style. Just plain text.

I want to understand why this happens and learn from it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `userVersion = editElement.style;` Here you're assigning the element style to `userVersion` but in the __previous__ line (`let userVersion = editElement.innerHTML;`) you're assigning the HTML to that variable. So that's being immediately overwritten. What exactly is it you want to save to `userVersion`, the style or the HTML content?

Comment: `editElement.style`/`userVersion` is an object but `localStorage` only "knows" how to handle strings.

Comment: I also don't understand what u want the HTML or STYLE because  u call same variable for both "let userVersion = editElement.innerHTML;
  userVersion = editElement.style;"

Comment: @Andy - I want to save for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the Function `localStorage.set` can only save Strings, so it will call `.toString()` on the Object before it get stored and the Result of it is it's type `[object CSSStyleDeclaration]`. Did you tried to stringify it before you safe it?
`userVersion = JSON.stringify(editElement.style);`
`document.querySelector("#myNotes").style = JSON.parse(localStorage.userEdits);`

Comment: I'm afraid to say this one did not solve the problem. It returns a bunch of weird texts which probably is meant for console.